# Copy specific values from a column into a second column

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

In my database there are two columns of dates, one that records the order date and one that records the customer subscription date. Normally the latter should be prior to the order date. Sometimes, however, this is not the case and a situation like the following occurs.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"order_date":["25/01/2020","25/01/2020","27/03/2020","26/01/2020","27/02/2020"],
              "subscr_date":["25/03/2020","26/03/2020","25/03/2020","28/03/2020","29/03/2020"],
              "client_id":["A","B","A","C","D"]
             })
df["order_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["order_date"], format= '%d/%m/%Y')
df["subscr_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["subscr_date"], format= '%d/%m/%Y')

print(df)

  order_date subscr_date client_id
0 2020-01-25  2020-03-25         A
1 2020-01-25  2020-03-26         B
2 2020-03-27  2020-03-25         A
3 2020-01-26  2020-03-28         C
4 2020-02-27  2020-03-29         D
```

In this dataframe all customers ("A", "B", "C", "D") have a subscription date following the order date. In addition, customer "A" made two orders.

### Goal

My goal is to assign each customer's **first** order date as their subscription date.
So far my attempts have been as follows:

### Attempt 1

```
df.loc[df["subscr_date"] > df["order_date"], ["subscr_date"]] = df["order_date"]
```

The problem with this attempt is that it gives multitiple subscription dates to clients that have multiple orders.

### Attempt 2

First I filter the rows of my interest, then I **groupby** the *client_id* and in the end I calculate the min value for the *order_date* column.

```
df.loc[df["subscr_date"] > df["order_date"], ["order_date","client_id"]].groupby(["client_id"]).agg({"order_date":"min"})
```

The problem here is that I don't know how to assign that values to the corresponding *subscr_date* column.

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: is this what you are looking for? `df['subscr_date'] = df.groupby('client_id')['order_date'].transform(min)`

Comment: Does it work also on filtered rows? Like this: `df['subscr_date'] = df[df["subscr_date"] > df["order_date"], ["order_date","client_id"]].groupby('client_id')['order_date'].transform(min)` ?

Comment: It gives me an Error: `TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Comment: @rafspo see my edit for your solution with a where clause

Comment: this should work `data = df[df["subscr_date"] > df["order_date"]].groupby('client_id')['order_date'].transform(min); df.loc[df["subscr_date"] > df["order_date"], 'subscr_date'] = data`

Comment: @Chris it occurs the following error: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: @rafspo Did you split the code into two different lines after the semicolon or just run as it is written? Either should work as you are not assigning values to a function call.

Comment: @Chris Ah, I got the error! I switched the position, putting the function before the variable.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

we can use `groupby` with `min` and then `map` the values back onto your original df

```
df['subscr_date_min'] = df['client_id'].map(df.groupby(['client_id'])['order_date'].min())

print(df)

  order_date subscr_date client_id subscr_date_min
0 2020-01-25  2020-03-25         A      2020-01-25
1 2020-01-25  2020-03-26         B      2020-01-25
2 2020-03-27  2020-03-25         A      2020-01-25
3 2020-01-26  2020-03-28         C      2020-01-26
4 2020-02-27  2020-03-29         D      2020-02-27
```

you could also use `transform` which allows to `groupby` operations without modifying the index

```
df.groupby(['client_id'])['order_date'].transform('min')
#out

0   2020-01-25
1   2020-01-25
2   2020-01-25
3   2020-01-26
4   2020-02-27
```

for this exercise, it seems you only want to use this where the order date is less than the sub date

```
df['subscr_date_min'] = np.where(
    df["order_date"].le(df["subscr_date"]),
    df.groupby(['client_id'])['order_date'].transform('min'),
    df["subscr_date"],
)
```